# Problem saving image in external storage on android

Tags: java, android

I am writing a camera application for the android platform. I am using the CameraKitView Library for producing my camera view. Everything else including accessing the camera is working as expected except for actually capturing and saving the image. minimum sdk is 15 and target sdk and compile sdk is  28. The code for saving the image is as shown below

```
cameraKitView.captureImage(new CameraKitView.ImageCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onImage(CameraKitView cameraKitView, byte[] photo) {
            File savedPhoto = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "pchk.jpg");
            try{
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(savedPhoto.getPath());
                outputStream.write(photo);
                outputStream.close();
            }catch (java.io.IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance

Comment: What's the exception that you get?

Comment: I didn't get any exception or any error

Comment: Have you requested camera permissions at runtime? Set some breakpoints or log statements in your catch block and in the code above it and see where the execution is going.

Comment: The `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is also needed, I think.

Comment: I added the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in Manifest

Comment: I noticed the problem is permissions and I need to add permissions at runtime let me look into that and update

Comment: Since Android Marshmallow you need to request most permissions at runtime, as well as having them in your manifest. You will need CAMERA and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Answer (score 0):

First of all **verify** that your file or folder where you want to save a file **is exists or not**, if not create them

***capturedFolderPath** is a path of the folder where you want to create the file*

```
File folderFile = new File(capturedFolderPath)
if (!folderFile.exists()) {
folderFile.mkdirs();
}
    
    
 String imageNameToSave = "xyz.jpg";

 String imagePath = capturedFolderPath 
    + File.separator + imageNameToSave + ".jpg";
    
    
File photoFile = new File(imagePath);
if (!photoFile.exists()) {
photoFile.createNewFile();
}
```

after creating write the bytes on the file like this

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(photoFile);
outputStream.write(bytes);
outputStream.close();
```